# Javascript inside javascript

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I'm using a js gallery (photoswipe) and one of the slides isn't an image but has some html.

In that slide is event tracking on a form submit with `onmousedown`, which I can't get to work.

So I have:

```
some vars
items.push({ html: '<div and form start etc>
    <input type="submit" onmousedown="javascript:_paq.push(["trackEvent" etc ]);_paq.push(["etc"]);_paq.push(["etc"]);">
'});
```

I've learn by fiddling and trial and error, sorry for the newbie question.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: try escaping the inner `"`'s like `[\"trackEvent\" etc ]` and if that fails, move the inline onmousedown code and attach an event to the input instead

Comment: escaping didn't work, I'll try attaching to the input - you mean 'oninput'?

Comment: I've tried oninput and onsubmit but no luck - I'll add some extra information to the question

Comment: It might be useful to add that inside the _paq.push above is this code:  _paq.push(["trackEvent","Blog","Subscribe",location.pathname.substring(1)])    Is it the location.pathname.substring that is creating the problem?

Comment: Can you show what you escaped? I said **inner** did you just escape all the `"`'s

Comment: Also, what error is it showing in the console?

Comment: You should include all source code to reproduce issue

Comment: I escaped only these, using the code from above: onsubmit="javascript: _paq.push([\"trackEvent\",\"Blog\",\"Subscribe\",location.pathname.substring(1)]);"  There are errors in the console, there's just no entry in the piwik analytics which is what _paq.push is supposed to do

Comment: Sorry, "there are *no* errors in the console"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Injecting JS in this way is not the cleanest thing to do. Instead, you could consider an more global approach with event delegation:

Somewhere in your page, include a click listener:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if(event.target.classList.contains('js-track-subscribe-blog-location')) {
    _paq.push(["trackEvent","Blog","Subscribe",location.pathname.substring(1)])
  }
})
```

From the moment this script has run, anything on your page with the class `js-track-subscribe-blog-location` will trigger your tracking code when clicked.

Simply include the class on your `<input type="submit"` and it should work.

Comment: You are a star lipsumar!

Comment: I've added this and it works well for registering the event and pulling the url location. One of the 3 _paq.push's in the original code was for pushing information that was entered in the form, but this doesn't work, do you see anything off? _paq.push(['trackEvent','Blog','Subscribe',document.getElementById('form-option').value]);

Comment: If your field (`<select>` i suppose) is the only thing on the page with an `id="form-option"`, then it should work. That said, if you do get things from this form, you should consider working at the form level: https://jsbin.com/nasocolusa/1/edit?html,js,console,output